# Building Spring Boot Application - Maven Errors

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I've been trying to package my spring-boot application into a war file but the errors keep coming, I've solved 3 so far but I'm stuck with this one.

### Error

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:repackage
 (default) on project pns: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: 
A required class was missing while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:repackage: 
org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/LaunchScript
```

### App Properties

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>iq.pns.PushNotificationServerApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

### Build Config

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>WAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be a corrupted jar in your Maven cache. Try deleting that cache, or at least the `org/springframework/boot` part of it, and re-running the build

Comment: @AndyWilkinson ... deleted the entire .m2 folder and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a corrupted jar in the Maven cache, just like @AndyWilkinson suggested.

Solved by deleting the `~/.m2/repository` folderand letting Maven re-download everything.